# Does Command stay useful at higher levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

Does Command's effectiveness scale up as you level up and face greater challenges, or is it mostly only useful at the lower levels?

If its usefulness doesn't scale with you, does being able to cast it Quickened (as a Sorcerer) extend the range of levels at which it remains useful (by trading a Bonus Action for your enemy's Action and Movement)? This could be used to either grant Advantage on melee attacks ("Grovel"), or [provoke opportunity attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72345/does-using-flee-with-command-provoke-an-opportunity-attack) ("Flee"). In the latter case, you would be dealing damage with your Action and Reaction, and your enemy would essentially be foregoing its turn.

Further, with the Drop command, you could deprive an enemy of its weapons/implement/shield (i.e., Disintegrating/Burning it or grabbing it from the ground and moving/throwing them away).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A creature has to succeed on a saving throw to avoid the effect (PHB p. 223).

> The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command [...]

As your enemies grow in power, so do you. The saving throw is calculated as:

> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficient + your modifier

The modifier depends on your class. If you are a sorcerer, it is the modifier as shown for your Charisma.

So if you are a level 17+ character, you are not unlikely to have a Saving DC of about:

> 8 + 6 + 4 = 18

If you have a way to increase your Charisma up to 30 (unlikely, though) then you would get:

> 8 + 6 + 10 = 24

In other words, the odds remain about the same when you are at lower or higher level. However, the Command spell will be strong against henchmen of a powerful foe since those guys are likely of a lesser level. Something to keep in mind... Especially if you use a higher level spell slot and command several monsters simultaneously.

Some powerful creatures have very high Wisdom and will succeed more often. But really, most monsters don't have such a great Wisdom to start with.

However, you are certainly more likely to encounter creatures that are not affected by enchantment spells or have some resistance to magic allowing them to better resist your spells in general.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, however, Fey Ancestry doesn't protect against Command because it's not a charm/sleep effect. That's part of why it's a bit more powerful than similar mind-affecting spells.

Comment: Ah. Indeed. I removed the Fey reference.